# Ror definir mensajes de error cuando guardamos un array Rails

Tags: formularios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, validación

Tengo un formulario que envía un array para guardar n cantidad de registros, el tema es que `:name` no puede estar en blanco.
¿cómo hago para que cuando guarde o intente guardar me dé los errores encontrados en el formulario y no guarde ningún registro si alguno no cumple?, ya que ahora si guarda en que tiene `:name` pero no el que no tiene, pero persiste el input dentro de la vista. Si le doy a guardar, se duplicará el record.

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
   
    def create
        @documents = Document.create(document_params[:documents_attributes])

        # acá quiero renderizar los errores ejemplo:

        @documents.errors.each do |attribute, message|

          # según la documentación era algo así pero para nada estoy seguro

        end
    end

    private

    def document_params
        params.require(:documents).permit(documents_attributes:[:user_id, :company_id, :name, :document_type, :is_validated, :observations, :url])
    end

end
```

en mi modelo document.rb

```
validates :name, presence: {message:"El nombre no puede estar en blanco"}
```

los formularios los genero dinámicamente con javascript pero se verían así

```
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="company_documents_attributes_name_${count}">Nombre</label>
       <input class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre Archivo..." type="text" id="company_documents_attributes_name_${count}" name="${attribute}[][name]">
       <!-- Este div muestra los errores en name -->
       <div class="error "></div>
     </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-8">
       <div class="form-group">
         <label for="company_documents_attributes_observations_${count}">Observaciones</label>
         <input class="form-control" placeholder="Observaciones..." type="text" id="company_documents_attributes_observations_${count}" name="${attribute}[][observations]">
       </div>
    </div>
```

Estos input se repiten infinitamente a medida que se cumple una condición en mi javascript, esto crea el array.

```
{"documents"=>
  {"documents_attributes"=>
    [{"url"=>"",
      "name"=>"nombre 2",
      "observations"=>"",
      "user_id"=>"7",
      "company_id"=>"51"},
     {"url"=>"",
      "name"=>"nombre 1",
      "observations"=>"",
      "user_id"=>"7",
      "company_id"=>"51"}]},
 "commit"=>"Agregar archivos",
 "company_id"=>"51"}
```

He probado de varias formas pero no puedo implementar ninguna, alguna iluminación?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que deberías englobar todo dentro de una transacción, además de usar `create!` para que te arroje una excepción en caso de error y aborte la transacción.

```
Document.transaction do
  @documents = Document.create!(document_params[:documents_attributes])
end
```

Luego hacer un `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` para hacer manejo de errores.
Debes tener claro que de esta forma, al primer documento con error va a parar la transacción.